# Render partial for each element in list using Rails unobtrusive javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, unobtrusive-javascript

My controller returns a list of users and renders a javascript file (unobtrusive javascript).  I want to loop through that list of users and render a partial for each into a div.  I have the following code:

view:

```
<div id="searched-users-div"></div>
```

.js file returned from controller

```
$('#searched-users-div').html(
    "<%= 
        if @searched_users and @searched_users.length > 0
            @searched_users.each do |user|
                escape_javascript(render(:partial => "shared/user_block", :locals => { :user => user }))
            end
        end
    %>");
```

Prints this to the div:

```
[#<User id: 1, name:...>]
```

This doesn't seem to work.  It seems to just print the array as plain text, with no html or anything, inside the div.  Is there a way to loop through the @searched_users array and render a partial for each?

Or should I just create a new partial that accepts an array of searched_users, and loop through it inside that?

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'doesn't get past the first render' - are you seeing an error?

Comment: Sorry, updated my post. It prints the array as plain text inside the div.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes before and after the embedded ruby tags (`"<%=` and `%>"` should be `<%=` and `%>`).  And use `map` with `join` to concatenate the multiple renderings:

```
$('#searched-users-div').html(
    <%= j(if @searched_users
            @searched_users.map do |user|
              render(:partial => "shared/user_block", :locals => { :user => user })
            end.join("\n")
          else
            ''
          end) %>);
```

Comment: You might also want to move the conditional and the loop to handle the case where `@searched_users` is `nil`, otherwise you're going to be calling `.html(nil)` (or `.html()` with no content).